# EventHub Trigger to Functions cardinality with one causing higher timeouts

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

When I select many with "cardinality" in function bindings, it works fine.

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "eventHubMessages",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "sessions",
      "connection": "connectionstring",
      "cardinality": "many",
      "consumerGroup": "group1"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

when I select "one" in function bindings, getting higher timeouts.

```
   "cardinality": "one",
```

When I look at console, I could see there are multiple functions started,

```
2017-09-12T19:37:49.645 Function started (Id=f0ef1cd5-8331-448e-86c6-84c745bbab13)
2017-09-12T19:37:49.956 Function started (Id=26629395-54b8-4f83-9852-b3d55307318b)
```

Is cardinality "many" single threaded, and "one" is getting processed parallely. While I have no problem with parallel processing, it brings higher timeouts. or this is a core issue with Functions App?

The total "Function Started", I could see is close to 250.  Is scalability manager having issue here?

Comment: I think "many" should be used when you want to process multiple events in one function call (i.e. accept an array as parameter)

Comment: With the business process and time limitation for function is set to 5 minutes. I don't want the function to partially succedd and partially fail. If processing one by one makes the runtime with higher success rate and less failure rate, then that would be the way to go. But these timeouts issues causing difficulty processing one by one.

Answer (score 2):

Cardinality 'one' means that you get one function invocation per EventData payload. 
'Many' means that you get a whole batch of EventData[] per invocation. 
There's some more detail on the wiki at https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/EventHub-support

When reasoning about the correctness of your code, you should that function invocations *could* run in parallel and that batch sizes are random (unless you're very explicitly configuring that). A single batch will likely still run serially.

Comment: Thanks for the note. Are you sure it is running in Parallel?  If so, then Azure has scalability issues with Functions/AdJobs. It does not know to add more instances when the resource is needed. My coldstart on this function is not too high, creating new instances should not cause the caller for more time.

Comment: @Kannaiyan, I have some follow-up questions:

1) What language are you using for your Function code?

2) How are you determining that timeout is happening? Are you seeing the same message being processed again (i.e. you can tell that checkpointing is not happening)?  I want to verify that this is not a console logging issue.

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify that it *could* be running parallel (which is important o consider from a correctness perspective).

Comment: I use nodejs as language and App Insights reports on errors and timings. Same message gets processd again yes. The issue I see here is not with the function, but on the process whichever does the scaling.

Comment: @Kannaiyan, kindly open an issue at our GitHub repo (https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues) and provide use the following 1). The snippet for "Function started (Id={some Guid})" from one of the recent log entries (preferably < 2 weeks) of the effected Function. 2) The region the function was deployed in.